# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in : Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, insert

I have a team registration form on my joomla website and this error appears when the user goes to create a team.

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/xboxfifa/public_html/HD/components/com_joomsport/views/regteam/tmpl/default.php on line 21
```

Here is line 21.

```
$new_tmp = implode(',',$tmp);
```

Here is the full code.

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

`JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');
$new_temp = $Itemid = JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
$lists = $this->lists;
foreach ($this->lists['team_reg'] as $dta) 
{
    $tmp[]='\''.addslashes($dta).'\'';
}
$new_tmp = implode(',',$tmp);
```

Comment: @AngularAddict How do i define it as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error if your foreach loop never happens (if you have no `$this->lists['team_reg']` to loop over).

```
$tmp = array(); // do this just in case you have no records below
foreach ($this->lists['team_reg'] as $dta) 
{
    $tmp[]='\'.addslashes($dta).'\';
}
$new_tmp = implode(',',$tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $tmp is not defined as array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be defined like $tmp = array ();

Comment: $tmp[] is a valid shortcut, but see my answer.